# How to recover data from Firebase Firestore and convert to list Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have static data every time I want to display a map I have to add it to a list.

I want from Firebase to convert my database into a list.

How to retrieve data from Firebase Firestore to `List<card>`?

```
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Card {
  int id;
  String firstname, lastname, Phonenumber, age;

  double amount;
  List<Color> colors;

  Card({
    this.id,
    this.firstname,
    this.lastname,
    this.Phonenumber,
    this.age,
  });
}

List<Card> cards = [
  Card(
    firstname: "David",
    lastname: "smith",
    Phonenumber: "5555 5678 9101 ",
    age: '28',
  ),
   Card(
    firstname: "laila",
    lastname: "gotter",
    Phonenumber: "2555 1455 24445 ",
    age: '24',
  ),
   Card(
    firstname: "Jacob",
    lastname: "smith",
    Phonenumber: "5555 5678 9101 1123",
    age: '31',
  )
];
```

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/firestore/usage?

Comment: how to retrieve information from a firebase database and insert it into an instance of a class

Comment: Are you talking about serialization? If yes, there are many official examples in the firestore package itself. See [here](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/friendlyeats-flutter#0). This shows how to get data from firestore, create a class instance from it and display it.